# request example project with amcharts php mysql

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, charts

I have a small company and I need show my result from MySQL to amcharts. 
I am easy user and I study [this link](https://www.amcharts.com/tutorials/using-data-loader-to-connect-charts-to-mysql-data-base/) but can't use this tut for myself because i don't undestand each code for which file and what manage my files to show chart for example witch code depend html file or js or php file. 
i use netbeans and xampp for run codes. 
please help me and if you can send me exmaple file that i can use amcharts.

thanks a lot.

Comment: Welcome to SO.
Please read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)
and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
And [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to SO,

Here usually coders help for the major bugs which have been tried for long time still hard to find the solution and or help people who are constantly learning and facing some bugs...

For you, quick help I can give but you make sure you go through the code, learn some basics regarding that...

1. Download the link in tutorial [tutorial_assets_external-data_v3.zip](http://extra.amcharts.com/tutorials/external-data/tutorial_assets_external-data_v3.zip),  extract it and place it in htdocs in xampp folder(c drive or where you installed it).
2. Run XAMPP, open this localhost/phpmyadmin in browser and create a database named "test".
3. Open the database and import the data.sql in extracted folder.
4. Run in browser localhost/"specify_name_of_extracted_folder"

**Start small... Study the tutorial... enjoy coding**

Comment: where is tutorial_assets_external-data_v3.zip?